# problems in installing libxml2 on linux

Tags: ubuntu, libxml2

I am trying to install libxml2-2.9.1 on Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine. 
I followed the steps from both the links given below:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libxml2.html
http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/libxml/installation/installing_libxml_on_ubuntu_linux.php#comment

I am getting stuck after the compilation step. I am getting the same errors when I follow any one of the links. The error is

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/doc/examples'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/doc'
Making all in example
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/example'
  CC     gjobread.o
  CCLD   gjobread
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/example'
Making all in xstc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/xstc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/xstc'
Making all in python
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
  CC     libxml.lo
libxml.c:14: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [libxml.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1/python'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhijit/Documents/libxml2-2.9.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8):

You need python headers.  Since you're on Ubuntu, you can probably avoid compiling python.  Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and then compile libxml2.

Alternatively, the LFS link that you've posted points to instructions for compiling python.

Comment: Solves for me on CentOS - except in yum the package is called `python-devel`

Comment: In Cygwin, the package may be named ```python2-devel``` or ```python3-devel```.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need the Python bindings, configure libxml2 with

```
./configure --without-python
```

and you don't have to install the Python dev package.

Answer (score 2):

hi the problem occured with me too. even when python-dev package was installed so i copied all header files to python folder in libxml2 library.

cp /usr/include/python2.7/*.h ..../libxml2-2.9.1/python/

and this solved my problem.